# How to maximize an objective function in Python Gekko?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I'm trying to maximize profit in my optimization problem. When I use the Gekko `m.Obj` function, it always minimizes the profit.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
profit = m.Var(lb=1,ub=10)
m.Obj(profit**2)
m.solve(disp=False)
print(profit.value)
```

The reported optimal solution is `profit=1`. How can I switch to maximizing an objective function with Python Gekko so that the optimal solution is `profit=10`? I have multiple objectives in my problem. There are some that I want to minimize (utilities, feed material, operating expense) and others that I want to maximize (profit, production).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a negative sign on your objective function for maximizing.

```
m.Obj(-profit**2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Two new functions `m.Maximize()` and `m.Minimize()` are available in [Python GEKKO starting in version 0.2.4](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as shown in the [GEKKO Change Log](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). In addition to the accepted answer `m.Obj(-profit**2)`, another option for maximizing the profit is to use:

```py
m.Maximize(profit**2)
```

If you have all of the terms expressed in monetary units then you can minimize and maximize to have optimal tradeoffs to drive overall profitability without using the squared objective.

```py
m.Maximize(revenue)
m.Minimize(operating_cost)
m.Minimize(feed_cost)
m.Minimize(utility_cost)
```

Python GEKKO combines all of the objective terms into a single value as:

`minimize (-revenue + operating_cost + feed_cost + utility_cost)`

You can retrieve the final objective function value after a successful `m.solve()` with `m.options.OBJFCNVAL`. The reported value is in minimization form. If you need to report the maximum form, then you can multiply the objective function result by `-1`.

```py
print(-m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```